# How can I make that when I clic on one of the menu items, that page shows only posts with the same category?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have a blog wordpress in localhost. What I want to know before uploading is if it is possible to show just posts with a certain category in an specific page. I mean, to show category articles "cats", for example, in the "cats" page in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost any WP theme will include category archives. If you want to add them to a menu, go to Appearance/Menus, select the Menu you want to edit, and pick the Category you want from the Categories menu to the left. How the Category "page" or archive displays will in turn be determined by your theme template, though a developer can also customize a specific Category template to show anything you want virtually any way that you want.

Comment: I didn't know I could use categories as menu items like that... I thought I had to use some php in my theme's code. Thank you so much!